# Just a survey which platform is better to use

Tags: android, windows, mobile

Which is the best platform for Mobile Development? Please Give me an IDEA..

Thanks,

Comment: Steve, I think this is programming related questions site, not for doing survey here.

Comment: Yep cause I'm going to create a mobile app that's why I'm asking...If you can't help just ignore it.. No need to down vote...zzzz

Comment: Steve, yah but this not for asking for survey here, if you have any doubt in programming then ask here, otherwise here many more sites with SO you can ask.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying get an opinion from some expert here...

Comment: ok then let me give it to you ok, happy.

Comment: In which technology you wants to develop?

Comment: probably in all mobile devices...must be fitted to all os..

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to develop mobile app in all platform, then you can develop app individually with all the platform, for that you must need to have knowledge as below:

1) Android: You must have knowledge about **Java** and **Android SDK**. IDE will be used either **Eclipse** or **Android Studio**.

2) iPhone : You must have knowledge about **IOS**, **XCode**, **Swift** (latest programming language from Apple).

3) Blackberry : You must have knowledge about **Java**.

4) Cross Platform: If you want to develop single app which will runs on all the platform then you must need to have a knowledge regarding cross platform that contains **PhoneGap**, **Xamarin** and many more, but these 2 are very famous now a days. For that you must need a knowledge about **HTML5**, **Java Script**, **HTML** etc.